# Archivos y lista enlazada en C

Tags: c, revisión-de-código

Tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio, estoy haciendo un registro con archivos binarios y una lista enlazada.

Mi problema consiste en que cuando hago el registro la primera vez puedo ver los registros que están en el archivo y que están en la lista. Para otra ejecución, tengo una función que trata de cargar los registros que están en el archivo en la lista para usar la lista para modificaciones y no el archivo directamente, pero al cargar la lista se queda como en un bucle infinito, cuando intento ver lo que cargo se imprime infinitamente el último registro de la lista y tampoco puedo seguir metiendo registros en la lista.

Pensé que era porque escribía con punteros en el archivo por eso en la función guardar uso otra variable, pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES "Locutores/Locutores.bin"
#define MAX_NOMBRE 30
#define MAX_APELLIDO 50
typedef struct Persona{
    int edad;
    char nombre[MAX_NOMBRE];
    char apellido[MAX_APELLIDO];
    int cedula;
}Persona;

typedef struct empleado{
    int sueldo;
    //int horario_de_entrada;
    //int horario_de_salida;
    int activo;
    int id;
}Empleado;

typedef struct locutor{
    Persona persona_locutor;
    Empleado empleado_locutor;
    struct locutor *sig;
}Locutor;

typedef struct radio{
    Locutor *lista_de_locutores;
}Radio;

void pausar(){
  printf("Ingrese cualquier tecla para continuar...\n");
  getch();
}

Radio iniciarLista(){
  Radio estacion_de_radio;
  estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores=NULL;
  return estacion_de_radio;
}

void guardarLocutor(Locutor *nuevoLocutor){
  FILE *file;
  Locutor nuevoLocutorA;
  strcpy(nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.nombre,nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre);
  strcpy(nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.apellido,nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido);
  nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.edad=nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.edad;
  nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.cedula=nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.cedula;
  nuevoLocutorA.empleado_locutor.sueldo=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo;
  nuevoLocutorA.empleado_locutor.id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
  nuevoLocutorA.empleado_locutor.activo=1;
  file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"ab");
  if(!file){
    printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo para guardar Locutor\n");
    pausar();
    exit(1);
  }else{
    fwrite(&nuevoLocutorA, sizeof(Locutor), 1,file);
  }
  fclose(file);
}

void ingresarLocutorALaLista(Radio *estacion_de_radio, Locutor *nuevoLocutor, int guardar){
  nuevoLocutor->sig=NULL;
  if(!estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores){
    estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores=nuevoLocutor;
    if (guardar)
      guardarLocutor(nuevoLocutor);
  }
  else{
    Locutor *listaAuxiliar;
    listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores;
    while(listaAuxiliar->sig)
      listaAuxiliar=listaAuxiliar->sig;
    listaAuxiliar->sig=nuevoLocutor;
    if (guardar)
      guardarLocutor(nuevoLocutor);
  }

}

Radio registroLocutor(Radio estacion_de_radio){
  system("cls");

  Locutor *nuevoLocutor;
  nuevoLocutor=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));

  if(!nuevoLocutor){
    printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria para el nuevo locutor\n");
    pausar();
    exit(1);
  }
  else{
    FILE * file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
    int id=0;

    fseek(file,(sizeof(Locutor)*(-1)),SEEK_END);
    while(fread(nuevoLocutor,sizeof(Locutor),1,file))
      id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
    //Rebobinar el archivo
    rewind(file);

    printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo locutor: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre);

    printf("Ingrese el apellido del nuevo locutor: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido);

    printf("Ingrese la cedula del locutor \n");
    scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.cedula);

    printf("Ingrese la edad del nuevo locutor: \n");
    scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.edad);

    printf("Ingrese el sueldo del nuevo locutor: \n");
    scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo);
    id++;
    nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id=id;
    nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.activo=1;
    nuevoLocutor->sig=NULL;
    fclose(file);
    ingresarLocutorALaLista(&estacion_de_radio,nuevoLocutor,1);
  }
  return estacion_de_radio;
}
void mostrarListaDeLocutores2(Radio estacion_de_radio){
  Locutor *listaAuxiliar;

  listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores;
  system("cls");
  printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
  while(listaAuxiliar){ 

    printf("%-10s %-20i %-10s %-10s %-10i %-10i %-10i %-10s \n"," ",listaAuxiliar->empleado_locutor.id,
           listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.nombre,
           listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.apellido,
           listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.cedula,
           listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.edad,
           listaAuxiliar->empleado_locutor.sueldo,
           "Nombre del programa");
    listaAuxiliar=listaAuxiliar->sig;
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("\t \t \t \t  PRESIONA CUALQUIER TECLA PARA VOLVER...");
  getch();
}

void mostrarListaDeLocutores(Radio estacion_de_radio){
  system("cls");
  FILE *file;
  file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
  Locutor *locutorALeer;

  locutorALeer=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));
  if(!file){
    system("cls");
    printf("La lista esta vacia\n");
  }else{
    printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
    while(fread(locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
      printf("%-10s %-20i %-10s %-10s %-10i %-10i %-10i %-10s \n"," ",locutorALeer->empleado_locutor.id,
             locutorALeer->persona_locutor.nombre,
             locutorALeer->persona_locutor.apellido,
             locutorALeer->persona_locutor.cedula,
             locutorALeer->persona_locutor.edad,
             locutorALeer->empleado_locutor.sueldo,
             "Nombre del programa");
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("\t \t \t \t  PRESIONA CUALQUIER TECLA PARA VOLVER...");
  getch();
}

Radio cargarListaLocutores(){
  Radio estacion_de_radio;
  estacion_de_radio=iniciarLista();
  system("cls");
  FILE *file;
  file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
  Locutor *locutorALeer;
  locutorALeer=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));

  if(!file){
    system("cls");
    printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
  }else{
    while(fread(locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
      ingresarLocutorALaLista(&estacion_de_radio,locutorALeer,0);
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
  return estacion_de_radio;
}

void menu (Radio estacion_de_radio){
  int op=0;

  do{
    system("cls");
    printf("[1] Registro de Locutor \n");
    printf("[2] Mostrar lista de locutores del archivo \n");
    printf("[3] Mostrar lista de locutores de lista enlazada \n");
    printf("[4] Salir \n");
    printf("Ingrese la opcion: ");
    scanf("%i",&op);

    switch(op){
      case 1: estacion_de_radio= registroLocutor(estacion_de_radio); break;
      case 2: mostrarListaDeLocutores(estacion_de_radio); break;
      case 3: mostrarListaDeLocutores2(estacion_de_radio); break;
      case 4: exit(1);
      default :
        printf("%cLa opcion que ingreso no es correcta!",173);
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
    }
  }while(op!=7);
}

int main (){

  Radio mi_estacion_de_radio;
  mi_estacion_de_radio=cargarListaLocutores();
  menu(mi_estacion_de_radio);
  free(mi_estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores);
  pausar();
  return 0;
}
```

EDITO: Después de ciertos comentarios mi código actual es el siguiente, aunque sigue teniendo problemas ya que se queda colgado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES "Locutores/Locutores.bin"
#define MAX_NOMBRE 30
#define MAX_APELLIDO 50

typedef struct Persona{
    int edad;
    char nombre[MAX_NOMBRE];
    char apellido[MAX_APELLIDO];
   int cedula;
}Persona;

typedef struct empleado{
    int sueldo;
    //int horario_de_entrada;
    //int horario_de_salida;
    int activo;
    int id;
}Empleado;

typedef struct locutor{
    Persona persona_locutor;
    Empleado empleado_locutor;
    struct locutor *sig;
}Locutor;

typedef struct radio{
    Locutor *lista_de_locutores;
}Radio;

void pausar(){
    printf("Ingrese cualquier tecla para continuar...\n");
    getch();
}

void iniciarLista(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores=NULL;
}

void guardarLocutor(Locutor *nuevoLocutor){
    FILE *file;
    Locutor nuevoLocutorA;
        strcpy(nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.nombre,nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre);
        strcpy(nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.apellido,nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido);
        nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.edad=nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.edad;
        nuevoLocutorA.persona_locutor.cedula=nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.cedula;
        nuevoLocutorA.empleado_locutor.sueldo=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo;
        nuevoLocutorA.empleado_locutor.id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
        nuevoLocutorA.empleado_locutor.activo=1;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"ab");
    if(!file){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo para guardar Locutor\n");
            pausar();
            exit(1);
    }else{
        fwrite(&nuevoLocutorA, sizeof(Locutor), 1,file);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void ingresarLocutorALaLista(Radio *estacion_de_radio, Locutor *nuevoLocutor, int guardar){
    if(!estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores){
        estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores=nuevoLocutor;
            if (guardar)
                guardarLocutor(nuevoLocutor);
    }
    else{
        Locutor *listaAuxiliar;
        listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores;
        while(listaAuxiliar->sig)
            listaAuxiliar=listaAuxiliar->sig;
        listaAuxiliar->sig=nuevoLocutor;
            if (guardar)
                guardarLocutor(nuevoLocutor);
    }
}

void registroLocutor(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    system("cls");

    Locutor *nuevoLocutor;
    nuevoLocutor=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));

    if(!nuevoLocutor){
        printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria para el nuevo locutor\n");
        pausar();
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        FILE * file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
        int id=0;

        fseek(file,(sizeof(Locutor)*(-1)),SEEK_END);
        while(fread(nuevoLocutor,sizeof(Locutor),1,file))
            id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
        //Rebobinar el archivo
        rewind(file);

        printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo locutor: \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre);

        printf("Ingrese el apellido del nuevo locutor: \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido);

        printf("Ingrese la cedula del locutor \n");
        scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.cedula);

        printf("Ingrese la edad del nuevo locutor: \n");
        scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.edad);

        printf("Ingrese el sueldo del nuevo locutor: \n");
        scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo);
        id++;
        nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id=id;
        nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.activo=1;
        nuevoLocutor->sig=NULL;
        fclose(file);
        ingresarLocutorALaLista(estacion_de_radio,nuevoLocutor,1);
    }
}
void mostrarListaDeLocutores2(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    Locutor *listaAuxiliar;

    listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores;
    system("cls");
    printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
    while(listaAuxiliar){

        printf("%-10s %-20i %-10s %-10s %-10i %-10i %-10i %-10s \n"," ",listaAuxiliar->empleado_locutor.id,
       listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.nombre,
       listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.apellido,
       listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.cedula,
       listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.edad,
       listaAuxiliar->empleado_locutor.sueldo, "Nombre del programa");
        listaAuxiliar=listaAuxiliar->sig;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t \t \t \t  PRESIONA CUALQUIER TECLA PARA VOLVER...");
    getch();
}

void mostrarListaDeLocutores(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    system("cls");
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
    Locutor *locutorALeer;

    locutorALeer=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));
     if(!file){
        system("cls");
        printf("La lista esta vacia\n");
     }else{
         printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
         while(fread(locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
           printf("%-10s %-20i %-10s %-10s %-10i %-10i %-10i %-10s \n"," ",locutorALeer->empleado_locutor.id,
           locutorALeer->persona_locutor.nombre,
           locutorALeer->persona_locutor.apellido,
           locutorALeer->persona_locutor.cedula,
           locutorALeer->persona_locutor.edad,
           locutorALeer->empleado_locutor.sueldo,
           "Nombre del programa");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t \t \t \t  PRESIONA CUALQUIER TECLA PARA VOLVER...");
    getch();
}

void cargarListaLocutores(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    //INICIO LA LISTA DE LOCUTORES EN NULL
    iniciarLista(estacion_de_radio);
    system("cls");
    //TRATO DE LEER EL ARCHIVO PARA CARGAR LAS LISTAS
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
    Locutor *locutorALeer;
    locutorALeer=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));
    //SI NO SE PUDO LEER ES PORQUE NO EXISTE
     if(!file){
        system("cls");
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
     }else{
     //DE OTRA MANERA MIENTRAS VAYA LEYENDO EL LOCUTOR QUE LO VAYA INGRENSANDO EN LA LISTA  
         while(fread(locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
            locutorALeer->sig=NULL;
           ingresarLocutorALaLista(estacion_de_radio,locutorALeer,0);
         }
     }
     fclose(file);
}

void menu (Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    int op=0;

    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("[1] Registro de Locutor \n");
        printf("[2] Mostrar lista de locutores del archivo \n");
        printf("[3] Mostrar lista de locutores de lista enlazada \n");
        printf("[4] Salir \n");
        printf("Ingrese la opcion: ");
        scanf("%i",&op);

        switch(op){
            case 1: registroLocutor(estacion_de_radio); break;
            case 2: mostrarListaDeLocutores(estacion_de_radio); break;
            case 3: mostrarListaDeLocutores2(estacion_de_radio); break;
            case 4: exit(1);
            default :
                      printf("%cLa opcion que ingreso no es correcta!",173);
                      Sleep(1000);
                      system("cls");
        }
    }while(op!=7);
}

int main (){
    //INSTANCIAR RADIO QUE CONTIENE TODAS LAS ESTRUCTURAS
    Radio mi_estacion_de_radio;
    //CARGAR LA LISTA CON LOS REGISTROS DEL ARCHIVO
    cargarListaLocutores(&mi_estacion_de_radio);
    menu(&mi_estacion_de_radio);
    free(mi_estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores);
    pausar();
    return 0;
}
```

EDITO: Segunda edición del código en mejora de las funciones pero el problema aun persiste.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES "Locutores/Locutores.bin"
#define MAX_NOMBRE 30
#define MAX_APELLIDO 50
typedef struct Persona{
    int edad;
    char nombre[MAX_NOMBRE];
    char apellido[MAX_APELLIDO];
   int cedula;
}Persona;

typedef struct empleado{
    int sueldo;
    //int horario_de_entrada;
    //int horario_de_salida;
    int activo;
    int id;
}Empleado;

typedef struct locutor{
    Persona persona_locutor;
    Empleado empleado_locutor;
    struct locutor *sig;
}Locutor;

typedef struct radio{
    Locutor *lista_de_locutores;
}Radio;

void pausar(){
    printf("INGRESE CUALQUIER TECLA PARA CONTINUAR...\n");
    getch();
}
void errorCritico()
{
  printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria\n");
  pausar();
  exit(1);
}

void iniciarLista(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores=NULL;
}

void guardarLocutor(Locutor *nuevoLocutor){
    FILE *file;

    file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"ab");
    if(!file){
        errorCritico();
    }else{
        fwrite(nuevoLocutor, sizeof(Locutor), 1,file);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void ingresarLocutorALaLista(Radio *estacion_de_radio, Locutor *nuevoLocutor){
    if(!estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores){
        estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores=nuevoLocutor;
    }
    else{
        Locutor *listaAuxiliar;
        listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores;
        while(listaAuxiliar->sig)
            listaAuxiliar=listaAuxiliar->sig;
        listaAuxiliar->sig=nuevoLocutor;

    }
}

void registroLocutor(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    system("cls");

    Locutor *nuevoLocutor;
    nuevoLocutor=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));

    if(!nuevoLocutor){
        errorCritico();
    }
    else{
        FILE * file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
        int id=0;

        fseek(file,(sizeof(Locutor)*(-1)),SEEK_END);
        if(fread(nuevoLocutor,sizeof(Locutor),1,file))
            id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;

        printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo locutor: \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre);

        printf("Ingrese el apellido del nuevo locutor: \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido);

        printf("Ingrese la cedula del locutor \n");
        scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.cedula);

        printf("Ingrese la edad del nuevo locutor: \n");
        scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.edad);

        printf("Ingrese el sueldo del nuevo locutor: \n");
        scanf("%i",&nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo);
        id++;
        nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id=id;
        nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.activo=1;
        nuevoLocutor->sig=NULL;
        fclose(file);
        ingresarLocutorALaLista(estacion_de_radio,nuevoLocutor);
        guardarLocutor(nuevoLocutor);
    }
}

void imprimirLocutor(Locutor *locutor)
{
    printf("%-10s %-20i %-10s %-10s %-10i %-10i %-10i %-10s \n"," ",locutor->empleado_locutor.id,
        locutor->persona_locutor.nombre,
        locutor->persona_locutor.apellido,
        locutor->persona_locutor.cedula,
        locutor->persona_locutor.edad,
        locutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo,
        "Nombre del programa");
}

void mostrarListaDeLocutores2(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    Locutor *listaAuxiliar;

    listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores;
    system("cls");
    printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
    while(listaAuxiliar){
        imprimirLocutor(listaAuxiliar);
        listaAuxiliar=listaAuxiliar->sig;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t \t \t \t  PRESIONA CUALQUIER TECLA PARA VOLVER...");
    getch();
}

void mostrarListaDeLocutores(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    system("cls");
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
    Locutor locutorALeer;

    printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
    while(fread(&locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
        imprimirLocutor(&locutorALeer);
    }       
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t \t \t \t  PRESIONA CUALQUIER TECLA PARA VOLVER...");
    getch();
}

void cargarListaLocutores(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    //INICIO LA LISTA DE LOCUTORES EN NULL
    iniciarLista(estacion_de_radio);
    system("cls");
    //TRATO DE LEER EL ARCHIVO PARA CARGAR LAS LISTAS
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
    //SI NO SE PUDO LEER ES PORQUE NO EXISTE
     if(!file){
        system("cls");
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        pausar();
     }else{
        Locutor *locutorALeer;
        locutorALeer=(Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));

     //DE OTRA MANERA MIENTRAS VAYA LEYENDO EL LOCUTOR QUE LO VAYA INGRENSANDO EN LA LISTA  
         while(fread(locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
            locutorALeer->sig=NULL;
            ingresarLocutorALaLista(estacion_de_radio,locutorALeer);
         }
     }
     fclose(file);
}

void eliminarListaLocutor(Radio * estacion_de_radio){
    Locutor *listaAuxiliar;
    while(estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores){
        listaAuxiliar=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores;
        estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores=estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores->sig;
        free(listaAuxiliar);
    }
} 

void menu (Radio *estacion_de_radio){
    int op=0;

    do{
    system("cls");
    printf("[1] Registro de Locutor \n");
    printf("[2] Mostrar lista de locutores del archivo \n");
    printf("[3] Mostrar lista de locutores de lista enlazada \n");
    printf("[4] Salir \n");
    printf("Ingrese la opcion: ");
    scanf("%i",&op);

    switch(op){
        case 1: registroLocutor(estacion_de_radio); break;
        case 2: mostrarListaDeLocutores(estacion_de_radio); break;
        case 3: mostrarListaDeLocutores2(estacion_de_radio); break;
        case 4: eliminarListaLocutor(estacion_de_radio);
                free(estacion_de_radio->lista_de_locutores);
                exit(1);
        default :
                  printf("%cLa opcion que ingreso no es correcta!",173);
                  Sleep(1000);
                  system("cls");
    }
    }while(op!=7);
}

int main (){
    //INSTANCIAR RADIO QUE CONTIENE TODAS LAS ESTRUCTURAS
    Radio mi_estacion_de_radio;
    //CARGAR LA LISTA CON LOS REGISTROS DEL ARCHIVO
    cargarListaLocutores(&mi_estacion_de_radio);
    menu(&mi_estacion_de_radio);
    pausar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu programa está cargado de errores y de código complicado en exceso para lo que se supone que tiene que hacer. Te comento algunas cosas:

```
while(fread(nuevoLocutor, sizeof(Locutor),1, file))
  id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
```

Otro aspecto que me llama la atención de ese código es la línea inmediatamente anterior:

```
static int id=0;
while(fread(nuevoLocutor, sizeof(Locutor),1, file))
  id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
```

Usar la variable estática tendría sentido si ese id únicamente lo calculases una vez al inicio del programa. La realidad es que el id se va a calcular cada vez que llames a la función, luego el modificador `static` sobra.

```
printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo locutor: \n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(nombre);
```

Y vuelvo a insistir: `fflush` **no debe usarse** con buffers de entrada.

```
strcpy(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre,nombre);
strcpy(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido,apellido);
nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.edad=edad;
nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.cedula=cedula;
nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.sueldo=sueldo;
nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id=id;
nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.activo=1;
nuevoLocutor->sig=NULL;
```

Estás trabajando el doble con esta dinámica. Lo recomendable en tu caso es almacenar los datos directamente en la estructura. ¿Por qué si así también funciona? Básicamente porque reducir las líneas de código reduce también los posibles puntos de error... y porque tardarás menos en terminar tu programa:

```
printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo locutor: \n");
gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.nombre);

printf("Ingrese el apellido del nuevo locutor: \n");
gets(nuevoLocutor->persona_locutor.apellido);

// ...
```

Si tu intención es quedarte con únicamente el último registro del fichero hay formas más rápidas de conseguirlo. Una opción sería usar fseek para moverse directamente al último registro y realizar una única lectura.

```
Locutor *nuevoLocutor;
nuevoLocutor=(Locutor*)malloc(sizeof(Locutor));
FILE * file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
if(!nuevoLocutor){
```

A eso se le llama tirar la piedra y esconder la mano. Intentas hacer una reserva de memoria, seguidamente abres el fichero y ya después compruebas si la reserva se ha realizado. ¿Te has planteado qué puede llegar a suceder si dejas el fichero abierto? Lo lógico es hacer la comprobación nada más reservar la memoria. También se te ha pasado verificar que el fichero se ha abierto correctamente:

```
Locutor *nuevoLocutor = (Locutor*)malloc(sizeof(Locutor));
if(!nuevoLocutor){
  // ...
}
FILE * file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
if( file ){
  // ...
}
```

También tienes muchas lagunas en el uso de punteros:

```
typedef struct radio{
    Locutor *lista_de_locutores;
}Radio;

Radio iniciarLista(Radio estacion_de_radio){
  estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores=NULL;
  return estacion_de_radio;
}

Locutor * cargarListaLocutores(Radio estacion_de_radio);

int main (){

  Radio mi_estacion_de_radio;

  mi_estacion_de_radio=iniciarLista(mi_estacion_de_radio);
  mi_estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores=cargarListaLocutores(mi_estacion_de_radio);
```

Esta estructura no tiene ningún sentido. `iniciarLista` se supone que sirve para incializar correctamente un objeto de tipo `Radio`. ¿Qué sucede si recibe un objeto que ya tiene datos? al asignar `NULL` al puntero acabas con lagunas de memoria.

En el caso de `cargarListaLocutores` pasa algo parecido. Recibe un objeto de tipo `Radio` por copia el cual se dedica a manipular para luego retornarlo. Salvo que tengas el requisito expreso de fusionar listas, que no es el caso, lo más limpio es que la función cree internamente su objeto de tipo `Radio`, lo rellene y finalmente lo devuelva. ¿Por qué todo esto? Porque al pasar `Radio` por valor consigues que los cambios que aplicas al objeto sean locales. Dicho con un ejemplo concreto que da lugar al fallo que comentas: Si llamas a `ingresarLocutorALaLista` y le pasas un objeto vacío de tipo `Radio` por valor la función hace:

```
estacion_de_radio.lista_de_locutores=nuevoLocutor
```

... pero el cambio es local y no se ve reflejado fuera de la función, luego el objeto `Radio` original sigue sin tener elementos.

Un diseño un poco más apropiado:

```
Radio iniciarLista(void){
  Radio estacion;
  estacion.lista_de_locutores=NULL;
  return estacion;
}

Radio cargarListaLocutores(void)
{
  Radio estacion = inicializarLista();
  // ...
  return estacion;
}

void ingresarLocutorALaLista(Radio* estacion,Locutor* nuevoLocutor)
{
  if( !estacion->lista_de_locutores )
    estacion->lista_de_locutores = nuevoLocutor;
  else
  {
    Locutor *ptr = estacion->lista_de_locutores;
    while( ptr->sig )
      ptr = ptr->sig;

    ptr->sig = nuevoLocutor;
  }
}
```

Por otro lado, para no tener que controlar el `sig` de los nuevos nodos puedes optar por llamar a `calloc` en vez de a `malloc`. La diferencia es que `calloc` inicializa todos los bytes a 0, por lo que tanto punteros como cadenas quedará automáticamente inicializados:

```
Locutor *nuevoLocutor = (Locutor*)calloc(1,sizeof(Locutor));
```

Y un último consejo: Evita el código duplicado. Los mensajes de consola están, en el mejor de los casos, triplicados. Crea una función para imprimir un objeto de tipo `Locutor` y llama a dicha función en vez de repetir el código. No sabes lo complicado que es mantener código repetido por doquier.

EDITO: Respecto a tu actualización, mi crítica es la siguiente:

En la función `guardarLocutor` te puedes ahorrar la copia ya, que puedes guardar el puntero que te facilitan directamente:

```
void guardarLocutor(Locutor *nuevoLocutor){
  FILE *file;
  file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"ab");
  if(!file){
    printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo para guardar Locutor\n");
    pausar();
    exit(1);
  }else{
    fwrite(nuevoLocutor, sizeof(Locutor), 1,file);
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

Por otro lado, la mejor estrategia para que el código haga lo que pretendes y mantenga cierto orden es que intentes que cada función tenga una única responsabilidad. ¿A qué me refiero? Por ejemplo la función `ingresarLocutorALaLista` añade un elemento a la lista `Radio` y además se encarga de almacenar el registro en un fichero. Mal hecho. La función o añade un registro a la lista o guarda el registro en un archivo. Dotar a las funciones de varias responsabilidades produce acoplamiento y dificulta la reutilización del código. Lo ideal es que esa función únicamente añada elementos a la lista. Cuando quieras guardar el registro añade manualmente una llamada a la función ´guardar´.

Las siguientes líneas pueden ser conflictivas:

```
fseek(file,(sizeof(Locutor)*(-1)),SEEK_END);
while(fread(nuevoLocutor,sizeof(Locutor),1,file))
    id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
```

Si atendemos a la documentación de `fseek`:

> Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability).

Es decir, no es seguro que ´SEEK_END´ funcione en todos los sistemas. ¿Solución? puedes leer el tamaño del archivo y posicionarte usando esa referencia:

```
struct stat st;
stat(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES, &st);
fseek(file,st.st_size - sizeof(Locutor),SEEK_SET);
```

Por otro lado, dado que te estás posicionando en el último registro no tiene demasiado sentido usar ´while´ para leer los registros (solo pretendes leer uno). Lo más representativo en este caso sería sustituir ´while´ por ´if´ y añadir un mensaje si hay problemas. Nota también que posteriormente llamas a `rewind`. Si no vas a seguir trabajando con el fichero, como es este caso particular, lo mejor es que te ahorres esa llamada y cierres directamente el fichero:

```
if(fread(nuevoLocutor,sizeof(Locutor),1,file))
  id=nuevoLocutor->empleado_locutor.id;
else
 printf("Error de lectura");
fclose(file);
```

Nota que estás repitiendo el mismo mensaje para los mensajes de error. ¿Qué tal si aislas dicho código en una función?:

```
void errorCritico(const char* msg)
{
  printf("%s\n",msg);
  pausar();
  exit(1);
}

// ...
errorCritico("No se ha podido reservar memoria para el nuevo locutor");
```

En `mostrarListaDeLocutores` no es necesario que uses memoria dinámica. En cualquier caso recuerda la norma: *Todo **malloc**/**calloc** debe ir acompañado del correspondiente **free***.

```
void mostrarListaDeLocutores(Radio estacion_de_radio){
  system("cls");
  FILE *file;
  file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb");
  Locutor locutor;

  if(!file){
    system("cls");
    printf("La lista esta vacia\n");
  }else{
    printf("%-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n"," ","Id Locutor","Nombre","Apellido","Cedula","Edad","Sueldo","Nombre del programa");
    while(fread(&locutor, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
      printf("%-10s %-20i %-10s %-10s %-10i %-10i %-10i %-10s \n"," ",locutor.empleado_locutor.id,
             // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Y bueno, lo que te comenté de aislar la función que imprime una instancia de tipo ´Locutor´ se ve que no lo has hecho.

```
void imprimirLocutor(Locutor* loc)
{
  printf("%-10s ...", locutor->empleado_locutor.id
}

void mostrarListaDeLocutores(Radio estacion_de_radio){
  // ...
  while(fread(&locutor, sizeof(Locutor),1, file))
    imprimirLocutor(&locutor);
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Realmente aprecio las correpciones como veras estoy empezando a practicar con este tema, trato de hacerlo lo más eficiente posible para mis conocimientos estos errores me ayudan mucho a progresar, también he mezclado mucho el codigo por asi decirlo porque comence de una forma termine de otra y es de prueba y error asi como eso que comentas  del static antes no leia del archivo gracias por la observación, voy reconstruir el código con tus indicaciones y te cuento

Comment: Ah lo del fflush(stdin) lo aprendi de un profesor me dijo que se usa para limpiar el buffer para que no haya entrada basura pero me gustaría que me explicaras

Comment: Sacado de la documentación de la función: "*In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (**but this is not portable expected behavior**).*" Es decir, que aunque funcione en algunos casos, no es una función pensada para un buffer de entrada.

Comment: Un detalle sobre la eficiencia: **ignórala**. Preocúpate por el rendimiento de una aplicación cuando no cumpla con las especificaciones. En programación tendemos a adelantar cual será el rendimiento de un algoritmo antes de haberlo probado y eso es un error. Intenta hacer código limpio y preocúpate del rendimiento cuando tengas motivos probados para ello.

Comment: He editado de nuevo el código y bueno en momento de ejecución funciona pero al volver ejecurtarlo tengo el mismo problema con la carga de la lista en el archivo estan los datos pero al leerlos y trata de cargalos se queda en ese bucle con el ultimo registro. Por favor si pudieras hacer otra revisión te lo agradeceria.

Comment: A la hora de editar la pregunta interesa conservar el historial. Si reformulas la pregunta y borras el contenido antiguo las respuestas que te han dado hasta ese momento dejan de ser válidas. Lo ideal es realizar una edición de la respuesta añadiendo el nuevo contenido pero sin borrar el contenido viejo.

Comment: He hecho algunos cambios con respecto a tus revisiones pero el problema todavia no lo hallo, la lista carga con los datos pero queda infinitamente en eso a la hora de mostrar la lista a la segunda ejecucion despues de haber cargado desde el archivo es como si no se detuviera y lee el ultimo registro siempre y al mostrar muestra infinitamente el ultimo registro

Comment: Es imprescindible aprender a usar el depurador de código. Quizás es un buen momento para investigar su uso

Answer (score 0):

Despues de un tiempo me di cuenta de mi error en la función `cargarListaLocutores` no reservaba memoria para cada nodo que iba a insertar sino que siempre usaba el mismo espacio de memoria reservado una vez la funcion quedaría así:

```
      void cargarListaLocutores(Radio *estacion_de_radio){
        //INICIO LA LISTA DE LOCUTORES EN NULL
        iniciarLista(estacion_de_radio);
        system("cls");
        //TRATO DE LEER EL ARCHIVO PARA CARGAR LAS LISTAS
        FILE *file;
        file=fopen(ARCHIVO_LOCUTORES,"rb+");
        //SI NO SE PUDO LEER ES PORQUE NO EXISTE
         if(!file){
            system("cls");
            printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
            pausar();
         }else{
            Locutor *locutorALeer;
            rewind(file);
            locutorALeer=(Locutor*)malloc(sizeof(Locutor));

         //DE OTRA MANERA MIENTRAS VAYA LEYENDO EL LOCUTOR QUE LO VAYA INGRENSANDO EN LA LISTA
            while(fread(locutorALeer, sizeof(Locutor),1, file)){
                ingresarLocutorALaLista(estacion_de_radio,locutorALeer);
                locutorALeer=(Locutor*)malloc(sizeof(Locutor));
            }
         }
         fclose(file);
    }
```

Por supuesto se debe iniciar en `NULL` el `sig` de los Nodos a insertar en la lista.